# Upgrading docker-compose in Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

According to the release notes for 1.23 (https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) it says:

> If you're a Mac or Windows user, the best way to install Compose and
>   keep it up-to-date is Docker for Mac and Windows.

Things I tried:

- Checking for updates in Docker for Windows (it was up-to-date yet `docker-compose -v` still returns 1.22)
- I tried uninstalling Docker for Windows and reinstalling it with a fresh download
- I tried installing docker-compose via pip but it still seems to run the docker-compose command from Docker for Windows and not the pip installed package.  I'm not sure how to set that up further.
- I tried the alternate curl code from the release notes for upgrading, but it is setup for linux I believe, so it simply gave me a permission denied.
- I tried to download the Windows .exe in the release notes but that didn't do anything when I ran it.

I need 1.23 because some Windows max path length issues were fixed, but it seems the Windows for Docker doesn't keep it up-to-date as it should and still distributes the 1.22 version of docker-compose.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved the problem:

- Download `docker-compose-Windows-x86_64.exe` from the release notes page
- Replace `docker-compose.exe` in `C:/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin` with that file.